# Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Observable<any>'

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular6, ng-upgrade

I am trying to get data from googleTagmanger. But I am getting error as "Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Observable'" Below is my code.

```
 this.translate.get('newtest.testsimulation').subscribe((res: String) => {
                pageLabel = res;
   });
```

Kindly help me to resolve this issue

**Note : I have just migrated my angular application from version 5 to 6. Earlier it was working fine.**

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with imports. try importing it like:
`import {Observable} from 'rxjs';`